# Referencing 2 foreign keys in Oracle

Tags: sql

I've got 3 schemas, Course, Takes, Instructs.

Under course, I have a course_id as primary key which I want to reference the attribute course_id in both takes and instructs. How can I do that?

Currently this is my course schema where I'm only referencing 1 other table

```
CREATE TABLE Course (
course_id int PRIMARY KEY REFERENCES Takes (course_id),
)
```

Comment: You have 3 _tables_.

Comment: Yes, in the table course I want to reference the other 2

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you don't have it backwards?

`Takes` references `Course`.

`Instructs` references `Course`

Would be a more normal arrangement.

You can do `ADD CONSTRAINT` after table creation if that's truly your model.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understood, you have the `Course` table with the primary key `course_id`. Then, there are tables `Takes` and `Instructs` and each of them has to reference the `Course` table (have `course_id` as a foreign key). In your query, `Course` references `Takes` but it has to be vice versa.
In case none of those tables exist you need to create them as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE Course (course_id INT PRIMARY KEY);

CREATE TABLE Takes (take_id INT PRIMARY KEY, course_id INT, 
    FOREIGN KEY (course_id) REFERENCES Course(course_id));

CREATE TABLE Instructs (instruct_id INT PRIMARY KEY, course_id INT,
    FOREIGN KEY (course_id) REFERENCES Course(course_id));
```

In case the tables `Takes` and `Instructs` already exist you should modify them with `ALTER TABLE`:

```
ALTER TABLE Takes
ADD CONSTRAINT fk_course
FOREIGN KEY (course_id)
REFERENCES Course(course_id);
```

And the same for the `Instructs` table.